# How to play audio file in media player

Tags: audio, android-intent, media-player, android-sdcard, playback

This is my Code Attach the media player but not playing sound

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView choose;
private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
private String[] mMusicList;
private ImageView b1, b2, b3, b4;
private ImageView iv;
private double startTime = 0;
private double finalTime = 0;
private Handler myHandler = new Handler();
;
private int forwardTime = 5000;
private int backwardTime = 5000;
private SeekBar seekbar;
private TextView tx1, tx2, tx3;
public static int oneTimeOnly = 0;
Uri uri;
String path;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    choose = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.choose);

    b1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button);
    b2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    b4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    tx1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    tx2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    tx3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);




    seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    seekbar.setClickable(false);
    b2.setEnabled(false);


    b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Playing sound", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
          }

            mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

            try {

                mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(MainActivity.this, Uri.parse(path));
                // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), contentUri), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                mMediaPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            mMediaPlayer.start();

            finalTime = mMediaPlayer.getDuration();
            startTime = mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

            if (oneTimeOnly == 0) {
                seekbar.setMax((int) finalTime);
                oneTimeOnly = 1;
            }
            tx2.setText(String.format("%d min, %d sec",
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) finalTime),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) finalTime) -
                            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) finalTime)))
            );

            tx1.setText(String.format("%d min, %d sec",
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) startTime),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) startTime) -
                            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) startTime)))
            );

            seekbar.setProgress((int) startTime);
            myHandler.postDelayed(UpdateSongTime, 100);
            b2.setEnabled(true);
            b3.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });

    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pausing sound", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mMediaPlayer.pause();
            b2.setEnabled(false);
            b3.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int temp = (int) startTime;

            if ((temp + forwardTime) <= finalTime) {
                startTime = startTime + forwardTime;
                mMediaPlayer.seekTo((int) startTime);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have Jumped forward 5 seconds", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot jump forward 5 seconds", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    b4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int temp = (int) startTime;

            if ((temp - backwardTime) > 0) {
                startTime = startTime - backwardTime;
                mMediaPlayer.seekTo((int) startTime);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have Jumped backward 5 seconds", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot jump backward 5 seconds", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    choose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent_upload = new Intent();
            intent_upload.setType("audio/*");
            intent_upload.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(intent_upload, 1);



        }
    });


}


private Runnable UpdateSongTime = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        startTime = mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        tx1.setText(String.format("%d min, %d sec",

                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) startTime),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) startTime) -
                        TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.
                                toMinutes((long) startTime)))
        );
        seekbar.setProgress((int) startTime);
        myHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
    }
};





protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {


    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


                uri = data.getData();

                Cursor returnCursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
                int nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
                returnCursor.moveToFirst();
                path = uri.getPath();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, path, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            // song.setText(returnCursor.getString(nameIndex));
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

}
```

this code is choose button select the audio file and select audio song

After the passing the uri media player parse the uri attach the url but does not playing sound

i have many code seen and use but not working this

please help me 
advance in thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final int SOUND_LOAD_REQUEST = 1;
ImageView choose;
private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
private String[] mMusicList;
private ImageView b1, b2, b3, b4;
private ImageView iv;
private double startTime = 0;
private double finalTime = 0;
private Handler myHandler = new Handler();
;
private int forwardTime = 5000;
private int backwardTime = 5000;
private SeekBar seekbar;
private TextView tx1, tx2, tx3;
public static int oneTimeOnly = 0;
Uri uri;
String path;
String ringtoneTitle;
Uri soundUri;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    choose = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.choose);

    b1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button);
    b2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    b4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    tx1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    tx2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    tx3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();


    seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    seekbar.setClickable(false);
    b2.setEnabled(false);

    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pausing sound", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mMediaPlayer.pause();
            b2.setEnabled(false);
            b3.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int temp = (int) startTime;

            if ((temp + forwardTime) <= finalTime) {
                startTime = startTime + forwardTime;
                mMediaPlayer.seekTo((int) startTime);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have Jumped forward 5 seconds", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot jump forward 5 seconds", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    b4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int temp = (int) startTime;

            if ((temp - backwardTime) > 0) {
                startTime = startTime - backwardTime;
                mMediaPlayer.seekTo((int) startTime);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have Jumped backward 5 seconds", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot jump backward 5 seconds", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    choose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent loadIntent = new Intent();
            loadIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            loadIntent.setType("audio/*");
            startActivityForResult(createChooser(loadIntent, "Select Audio"), SOUND_LOAD_REQUEST);

        }
    });


}


private Runnable UpdateSongTime = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        startTime = mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        tx1.setText(String.format("%d min, %d sec",

                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) startTime),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) startTime) -
                        TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.
                                toMinutes((long) startTime)))
        );
        seekbar.setProgress((int) startTime);
        myHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
    }
};






protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == SOUND_LOAD_REQUEST)
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

             soundUri = data.getData();

            try {
                mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, soundUri);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

            b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    mMediaPlayer.start();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Playing sound", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    finalTime = mMediaPlayer.getDuration();
                    startTime = mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

                    if (oneTimeOnly == 0) {
                        seekbar.setMax((int) finalTime);
                        oneTimeOnly = 1;
                    }
                    tx2.setText(String.format("%d min, %d sec",
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) finalTime),
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) finalTime) -
                                    TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) finalTime)))
                    );

                    tx1.setText(String.format("%d min, %d sec",
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) startTime),
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) startTime) -
                                    TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) startTime)))
                    );

                    seekbar.setProgress((int) startTime);
                    myHandler.postDelayed(UpdateSongTime, 100);
                    b2.setEnabled(true);
                    b3.setEnabled(false);
                }
            });
        }
}

 }
```

This code is finally working

Comment: Overrides the audio files application crash please help me